# How do I turn off COMMAND mode or VISUAL mode in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, if I press escape the page goes into COMMAND mode, which seems to take text input as commands, rather than actually typing the text.

Another oddity is the VISUAL mode, and I have no idea what it does besides it seems to highlight text.

I think they came installed with the theme that I got, 'soda', maybe. Anyway, I searched and found out you can turn off COMMAND mode by pressing 'i'.

Regardless, both of these modes are extremely annoying, how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default, sublime should ignore the vintage mode package. Right down the bottom of your default settings file change

```
"ignored_packages": []
```

to

```
"ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]
```

See: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html

Note: In this case you should be able to edit the sublime default but normally you would edit your user preference file.

Answer (score 21):

I knew the answer, but I'd been looking for it for a few days, so I figured I'd post it.

You have to disable the 'Vintage' package.

Go into Preferences > Package Control > Package Control: Disable Packages > Choose 'Vintage'

Comment: Also you can put into your user preferences:  "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ],

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me. In the default preferences it was set to:

```
"ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]
```

but in my user preferences it was set to:

```
"ignored_packages": []
```

Make sure that the value is not being overridden.